# C printing smilie face instead of chars

Tags: c

I saw a lot of threads with the same problem however my problem is a little more complicated. Here is the entire C code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define megisto_plithos 26

typedef bool typos_synolou[megisto_plithos];
typedef int stoixeio_synolou;

void Dimiourgia(typos_synolou synolo);
void Katholiko(typos_synolou synolo);
void Eisagogi(stoixeio_synolou stoixeio, typos_synolou synolo);
bool Melos(stoixeio_synolou stoixeio, typos_synolou synolo);
bool IsaSynola(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2);
bool Yposynolo(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2);
void EnosiSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou enosi);
void TomiSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou tomi);
void DiaforaSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou diafora);
void EmfanisiSynolou(typos_synolou synolo, char letters[]);



int main()
{
    char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


    typos_synolou agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos];
    Dimiourgia(agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos]);
    Katholiko(agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos]);
    EmfanisiSynolou(agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos], letters);
    typos_synolou S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos];
    Dimiourgia(S[megisto_plithos]);
    Dimiourgia(T[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(0, S[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(1, S[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(2, S[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(3, S[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(0, T[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(2, T[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(4, T[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(6, T[megisto_plithos]);
    Eisagogi(8, T[megisto_plithos]);
    printf("\n");
    EmfanisiSynolou(S[megisto_plithos], letters);
    printf("\n");
    EmfanisiSynolou(T[megisto_plithos], letters);
    printf("\n");
    if(IsaSynola(S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos]))
    {
        printf("ISA SYNOLA");
    }
    else printf("NOT ISA SYNOLA");
    printf("\n");
    if(Yposynolo(S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos]))
    {
        printf("S YPOSYNOLO T");
    }
    else printf("NOT S YPOSYNOLO T");
    printf("\n");
    if(Yposynolo(T[megisto_plithos], S[megisto_plithos]))
    {
        printf("T YPOSYNOLO S");
    }
    else printf("NOT T YPOSYNOLO S");
    typos_synolou enosi[megisto_plithos];
    printf("\n");
    EnosiSynolou(S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos], enosi[megisto_plithos]);
    EmfanisiSynolou(enosi[megisto_plithos], letters);
    printf("\n");
    typos_synolou tomi[megisto_plithos];
    TomiSynolou(S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos], tomi[megisto_plithos]);
    EmfanisiSynolou(tomi[megisto_plithos], letters);
    printf("\n");
    typos_synolou diafora[megisto_plithos];
    DiaforaSynolou(S[megisto_plithos], T[megisto_plithos], diafora[megisto_plithos]);
    EmfanisiSynolou(diafora[megisto_plithos], letters);
    return 0;
}


void Dimiourgia(typos_synolou synolo)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;

    for (i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
        synolo[i] = false;
}

void Katholiko(typos_synolou synolo)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;

    for (i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
        synolo[i] = true;
}

void Eisagogi(stoixeio_synolou stoixeio, typos_synolou synolo)
{
    synolo[stoixeio] = true;
}



bool Melos(stoixeio_synolou stoixeio, typos_synolou synolo)
{
    return synolo[stoixeio];
}



bool IsaSynola(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;
    bool isa;

    isa = true;
    i=0;
    while (i < megisto_plithos && isa)
        if (Melos(i,s1) != Melos(i,s2))
            isa = false;
        else
            i++;
    return isa;
}

bool Yposynolo(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;
    bool yposyn;

    yposyn = true;
    i=0;
    while (i < megisto_plithos && yposyn)
        if (Melos(i, s1) && !Melos(i, s2))
            yposyn = false;
        else
            i++;
    return yposyn;
}

void EnosiSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou enosi)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;

    for (i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
        enosi[i] = Melos(i, s1) || Melos(i, s2);
}

void TomiSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou tomi)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;

    for (i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
        tomi[i] = Melos(i, s1) && Melos(i, s2);
}

void DiaforaSynolou(typos_synolou s1, typos_synolou s2, typos_synolou diafora)
{
    stoixeio_synolou i;

    for (i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
        diafora[i] = Melos(i, s1) && (!Melos(i, s2));
}

void EmfanisiSynolou(typos_synolou synolo, char letters[megisto_plithos])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < megisto_plithos; i++)
    {
        if(synolo[i] == true)
        {
            printf("%c ", letters[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am in university and we have to create functions to use sets in C which we make with boolean arrays. The problem is that when i execute my program all the letters from before O show as a smiley face but after O they show normally. Also later when i print set union for example all the letters show as a smiley face. I read that the smiley face is random and i could get other emojis or charactes too but i am confused as to why half the letters show and the other half doens't. I tried switching A with O to see if the letter is the problem but i got the same result so it's not the letters problem. The first 14 characters of the string show as an emoji and the rest show normally. I also tried to make the array different like this:

```
char letters[] = {'A', 'B', 'C'...};
```

but i got the same result also.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mre]?

Comment: You mean to delete the uneccesery code?

Comment: Yes, one function should be enough. Also, enable more compiler warnings and fix all issues it reports. For gcc and clang, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` would be a good start

Comment: i use codeblocks cause this is the software they told us to use. It indeed has the gcc compiler but how can i enable more warnings?

Comment: W would suggest deleting the question instead of answering it as I do not think that this question and answer have any value to the community.

Comment: Also, this is an English community. Having functions and variables in a different language will make it much harder to read and fewer people will understand or take the time to understand it. You're more likely to get good answers if you make it as universally understandable as possible. And people with similar issues will more likely benefit from the question/answer.

Comment: Write code in English. It's madness to code in your native language. I did so too back in the days, until I realized it only meant that I had to learn twice the number of programming terms: the real one in English that everyone knows, and the useless one in my native language, which not even everyone knowing that language understands. Plus you quite often need to show your code to people who don't speak your native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define megisto_plithos 26
typedef bool typos_synolou[megisto_plithos];
```

This declares `typos_synolou` as a type of arrays of 26 `bool`s.

```
typos_synolou agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos];
```

This declares `agglika_kefalaia` as a variable that has a type of "array of 26 `typos_synolou`". Recall that `typos_synolou` is itself an array of 26 `bool`s. Consequently, `agglika_kefalaiaa` is an array of arrays, or a square 26x26 matrix.

```
Dimiourgia(agglika_kefalaia[megisto_plithos]);
```

This takes the element of `agglika_kefalaia` array with index 26 and sends it to a function. Note that `agglika_kefalaia` is an array of 26 elements. The indices change from 0 to 25 inclusive. Index 26 is *out of bounds*. The behaviour of the program is thus undefined.

What you really want is (using English names):

```
#define SIZE 26
typedef bool set_type[SIZE];

set_type english_caps; // note no [SIZE]

Initialize(english_caps); // note no [SIZE]
```

Same about all other variables and function calls.